# With Ajax Update panel, ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript is not working if placed in page_onerror

Tags: .net, asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager, ajax.net

I have a requirement to show user an alert box when there is some exception happened at page level (For different exceptions message is different).
In page I had two update panels and trigger based updates. And this functionality is common across pages. So I created a base page and tried to handle exception in page_onerror event. And I am using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...) to show alert for user.
If I use same code instead of throwing error in catch block, it is working fine. But if I throw exception and handling in page_error method, it is not working...

(As I am using update panels, I cannot use Response.Write for the same.)

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The page life cycle is slightly different in Async Postbacks - are you certain if `Page_OnError` is getting fired? If yes then perhaps the event fired so late that script manager has already rendered registered scripts into the output.

You should perhaps try [ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerror.aspx) event. If all you want to do is to show custom error alert then setting [ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerrormessage.aspx) property should do the trick.

I typically use `ScriptManager` in the master page and handles `AsyncPostBackError` event in the code behind to send back some custom exception. On java-script side, I use end request handler to show custom alert box. Check the example code from above MSDN link:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     if (args.get_error() != undefined && args.get_error().httpStatusCode == '500')
     {
        var errorMessage = args.get_error().message
        args.set_errorHandled(true);
        ToggleAlertDiv('visible');
        $get(messageElem).innerHTML = '"' + 
          errorMessage + '" ' + errorMessageAdditional;
     }
}
```